# run batch tasks concurrently, the tasks still in the initialization status

Tags: initialization, apache-flink, batch-processing

run 1.15.2 flink session on k8s，In most cases, there is no problem. Sometimes, tasks are initialized continuously, and subsequent tasks are also initialized continuously，

I run batch job with 6 concurrent,jobmanage with 2cpu and 3g Memory

This problem always occurs, it seems that there is a deadlock during initialization, but my job does not have any deadlock issues

i try to increase jobmanager io pool,it's still occur this problem